# When the kernel parameter of CUDA haven't any influence of the runtime

Tags: runtime, cuda

I have a CUDA program with huge memory accesses, which are 'randomly' and thus NOT coalesced at all. Now when I bench this program for different kernel-runtimeparameters and choose the blocksize always a multiple of 7 (starting from 7 to let's say 980) and the threadsPerBlock always a multiple of the warpsize (starting from 32 to let's say 1024) there's NO difference in the runtime of the program. How could one explain that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Out of matlab via tic,toc :) Okay I know there's the possibilty of using CUDA events but since the allocation and everything before the kernel call is the SAME for every call to my program, I don't think measuring only the kernel call will change the base of what I'm asking

Comment: I don't know how CUDA and Matlab work together, if you are just calling a CUDA C program from Matlab or some other thing, so I don't think I can help without more information (or even with :P).

Comment: Why is this so important to know? Okay some more information: A teacher gave me a task to program in parallel and he wants to know as a result, if this can be done or not. I came to the conclusion that it CAN'T be done just because the program is too data-intense and the read access is completely RANDOM and thus the runtime is very very bad. So my thoughts were that the runtime configuration hasn't got a very big influence since the program itself is so bad that it doesn't matter for performance which kernel-parameters to choose. But I just wondered if there are some more reasons to this...

Comment: ...which I could use to write down the conclusion on this subject; even if it's negative.

Comment: Are the results as excepted? I suppose with _NO_ difference you mean _very very_ small difference. Maybe your kernel has low computation compared to the time wasted moving the data so, you can not see the differences. It could also be related with tic/toc precision (wondering). I recommend time only the GPU time to see how the configuration work.

Comment: Could you provie some additional data on the kernel itself? In particular: how many registers and shared memory is it using? On what GPU you are running the tests? And what are your measured times? Also: `blocksize` and `threadsPerBlock` is the same thing in CUDA. I presume you meant `gridsize'?

Comment: @pQB: Yeah very small differences and yes the results are as expected since the kernel is accessing huge amounts of global memory in complete randomness. I'm testing on a GTX460. As the results are as expected (nearly no computation but HUGE memory access) I'm just thinking and asking for 'reasons' to explain it. The only reason which I thought of was the bad and uncoalesced and slow memory access so that numBlocks and threadsperblock haven't got a big influence. @Cygnus: About 34 registers and NO shared memory at all. And yes, I meant gridsize a.k.a. numBlocks :)

Comment: It seems your kernel occupancy is limited by registers. You could use the CUDA Occupancy Calculator to check it. I asked if the results were as excepted because i think you can not launch a kernel with 1024 threads per block using 34 registers by thread (neither with 992 threads per block). In that case your kernel fail to launch. So, in that case, your time is the same for both configurations. Did you check the results after each test?

Comment: Yes sure, this was just an example :) I run it with threads per block starting from 32 to about 960 or something like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Influence of thread block size is minimal. It's the last optimization I would try (and only if occupancy is egregiously bad, Fermi class has virtually same performance whenever occupancy is over 50% or so). If your kernel is really bad, then you won't notice any differences at all.

Also, you can run the CUDA Visual Profiler on your Matlab code. With GPU coding, profile everything.

Follow these steps in the session setup.

1. in Launch specify your Matlab executable.
2. In Working directory select the directory of your matlab script
3. in Arguments: -nojvm -nosplash -r name_of_matlab_script (with no .m)

That said, from personal experience, see if you can use texture memory to do some caching. Even if the memory accesses are not coalesced, you may nevertheless get some cache hits from memory locality.